# "relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'" when using a huge array

Tags: c++, linker-errors, large-data

The following C++ code is an MRE from my real code, removing absolutely everything that doesn't help trigger the error:

```
#include <cstring>

class X {
   private:
    char v[4L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L];

   public:
    X() {
        memset(v, 0, sizeof(v));
    }
};

int main() {
    static X x;

    return 0;
}
```

This is what I get when compiling with Clang 14:

```
/tmp/x-6d6700.o: in function `main':
x.cpp:(.text+0x11): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
x.cpp:(.text+0x1f): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
x.cpp:(.text+0x45): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
x.cpp:(.text+0x65): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Reducing the size of the array to less than 4 GB of RAM fixes it.

Although I already fixed this in my real code by using dynamic allocation, I'm still curious what causes it (I imagine it's due to the lack of 64-bit immediate encodings for some crucial instruction) and whether it'd be possible to fix it, maybe through some linker flags, without resorting to dynamic allocation.